# Encountered some exceptions while using Flink Table api to read from hive

Tags: hive, apache-flink

I'm using Flink table api to connect to hive, and below is the code:

```java
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inBatchMode();
TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
String name = "myhive";
String defaultDatabase = "fdl";

// using hive-site.xml in resource dir
HiveCatalog hive = new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, null);
tableEnv.registerCatalog("myhive", hive);

// set the HiveCatalog as the current catalog of the session
tableEnv.useCatalog("myhive");
Table table = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select count(1)\n" +
        "from fdl.user_info" +
        "where `date` = '20240102'");
        
table.execute().print();
```

Key dependencies are:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**And this is the exception I got:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.catalog.exceptions.CatalogException: Failed to list partitions of table fdl.user_info
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog.listPartitions(HiveCatalog.java:916)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.readPartitionFromCatalogWithoutFilterAndPrune(PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.java:342)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.readPartitionFromCatalogAndPrune(PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.java:332)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.readPartitionsAndPrune(PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.onMatch(PushPartitionIntoTableSourceScanRule.java:172)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.fireRule(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:337)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRule(HepPlanner.java:565)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRules(HepPlanner.java:428)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeInstruction(HepPlanner.java:251)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepInstruction$RuleInstance.execute(HepInstruction.java:130)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeProgram(HepPlanner.java:208)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.findBestExp(HepPlanner.java:195)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkHepProgram.optimize(FlinkHepProgram.scala:64)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkHepRuleSetProgram.optimize(FlinkHepRuleSetProgram.scala:78)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$2(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1$adapted(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.optimize(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:51)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$2(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1$adapted(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.optimize(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:51)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChainedProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1(FlinkChainedProgram.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChainedProgram.optimize(FlinkChainedProgram.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimizeTree(BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:93)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimizeBlock(BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:58)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.$anonfun$doOptimize$1(BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.$anonfun$doOptimize$1$adapted(BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.doOptimize(BatchCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.CommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimize(CommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.optimize(PlannerBase.scala:329)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:195)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1803)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:945)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1422)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.execute(TableImpl.java:476)
    at com.example.common.Test.main(Test.java:56)
Caused by: MetaException(message:NoSuchObjectException(message:Table user_info does not exist))
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partition_names_result$get_partition_names_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partition_names_result$get_partition_names_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partition_names_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_partition_names(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3053)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_partition_names(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3038)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionNames(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionNames(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1751)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.listPartitionNames(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2773)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.listPartitionNames(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.client.HiveMetastoreClientWrapper.listPartitionNames(HiveMetastoreClientWrapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog.listPartitions(HiveCatalog.java:902)
    ... 82 more
```

Further information:
Thers is also a werid thing happens. If I use

```java
tableEnv
  .from("fdl.user_info")
  .select($("ur_inf"))
  .filter($("date").isEqual("20240101"))
  .limit(10)
  .execute()
  .print();
```

instead of `tableEnv.sqlQuery`, I got the exception below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot resolve field [ur_inf], input field list:[app_id, user_id, ur_info, surplus, app, date].
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.failForField(ReferenceResolverRule.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.lambda$null$3(ReferenceResolverRule.java:87)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.lambda$null$4(ReferenceResolverRule.java:85)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.lambda$visit$5(ReferenceResolverRule.java:79)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.visit(ReferenceResolverRule.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule$ExpressionResolverVisitor.visit(ReferenceResolverRule.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.ApiExpressionVisitor.visit(ApiExpressionVisitor.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.UnresolvedReferenceExpression.accept(UnresolvedReferenceExpression.java:60)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule.lambda$apply$0(ReferenceResolverRule.java:47)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.rules.ReferenceResolverRule.apply(ReferenceResolverRule.java:48)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.ExpressionResolver.lambda$null$2(ExpressionResolver.java:247)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.resolver.ExpressionResolver.resolve(ExpressionResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.utils.OperationTreeBuilder.projectInternal(OperationTreeBuilder.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.utils.OperationTreeBuilder.project(OperationTreeBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.select(TableImpl.java:142)
    at com.exapmle.common.Test.main(Test.java:57)
```

This exception is as expected since [app_id, user_id, ur_info, surplus, app, date] are all the columns in user_info table and ur_inf is not in it. Its a typo. This means the connection is ok, and we got the meta data of user_info table, at least retrieving of columns are ok. The thing is, if I correct ur_inf to ur_info, I got the first exception again which is very confusing.

I asked chatGPT and Bard about the excpetion. They all told me it might due to a lack of permission or the existence of the table queried. I'm pretty sure that the table does exist. The problem should be something else. And I got empty result with **tableEnv.listTables()**.

1. Why does this exception occur? Is it due to a lack of permission?
2. If it's an issue of permission, where can I add authentication? Or what is the real problem if it isn't?

Comment: What hive version do you use ? Is it 3.1.2 ? You need to provide libraries in flink/lib too (flink-connector-hive_2.12-1.17.2.jar, hive-exec-3.1.0.jar, libfb303-0.9.3.jar). Check [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/)

Comment: My hive version is 3.1.3 and I run this on my local windows Intellij IDEA, so all the libs should be included.

Comment: How your Hive installed ? Is it Docker container ? In your code you gave **null** instead of `String hiveConfDir = "/opt/hive-conf"` so I suppose your Flink knows nothing about your Hive (`new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, null);`).

Comment: My Hive isn't in Dokcer. And give null value to hiveConfDir is ok, cause as you can see in the [HiveCatalog.java, createHiveConf](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/6e78eb18524ead3abd60da0ca41751b45e0e2482/flink-connectors/flink-connector-hive/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/catalog/hive/HiveCatalog.java#L265) method, if the hiveConfDir is null, it will try to find it in classpath.

Comment: I add some further information, it can prove the connection is ok.

Comment: Ok maybe **hiveConfDir** could be null, for me it never worked until I gave a right path but it wasn't on local env. Have you tried some basic stuff like `tEnv.listCatalogs()`,  `tEnv.listDatabases()`, `tEnv.listTables()` and describe your Table? To be sure your connection to catalog is OK. I suppose your **user_info** table is already created in Hive ?